Migrate from ListView to FlatList in ReactNative
I have been working on upgrading an old project (rn v 0.59.0) to rn v 0.74.3. I am currently stuck on migrating from ListView to FlatList. Specifically this code.
const listDataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
  getSectionData: SearchList.getSectionData,
  getRowData: SearchList.getRowData,
  rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => {
    if (row1 !== row2) {
      return true
    } else return !!(row1 && row2 && row1.matcher && row2.matcher && row1.matcher !== row1.matcher)
  },
  sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2
})

Is there an equivalent way to do this with FlatList? I am trying to maintain the current SearchList view if I can. I have tried using the 'deprecated-react-native-listview' package, but it's throwing a different error that I can't seem to resolve either.
ReactClassInterface: You are attempting to define `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` on your component more than once. This conflict may be due to a mixin.

